# Let $z=(x+y)e^y$ with $x=7t$ and $y=1-t^2$. Find $\frac{dz}{dt}$ as a function of $t$.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

So this is a chain rule question. So I drew out that I need $\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}$. I'm not sure if this is correct, but from here I computed that $\frac{dz}{dx}= x$, $\frac{dx}{dt}=7$,$\frac{dz}{dy}=ye^y$, and $\frac{dy}{dt}=(-2t)$. I then got $\frac{dz}{dt}=7x+ye^y(-2t)$, but this is not correct.

I still get confused on these and partial derivatives, on which variable is the constant and how to compute these.

Comment: Your derivatives for $z$ with respect to $x$ or $y$ need checking.

Comment: Your $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ are not correct. If your answer contains an $x$ or $y$ anywhere, it is not written "as a function of $t$".

Comment: It's helpful to notate the distinction between an "ordinary" one-variable derivative $\frac{df}{da}$ and a partial derivative $\frac{\partial g}{\partial b}$. (Use `\partial` to make the $\partial$ symbol in MathJax.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dz}{dx}= e^y$$
$$\frac{dz}{dy}= xe^y+e^y+ye^y$$

Comment: With this I know have $\frac{dz}{dt}=e^y(7)+xe^y+e^y+ye^y(-2t)$ but I'm still being told this is wrong

Comment: May be from you is required expression with "pure" $t$? Ask if you can and if yes, then  put all definitions of $y$ and $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake lies in how you computed the derivatives of $z$ with respect to either $x$ or $y$. You should have

$$z=(x+y)e^y\implies\begin{cases}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=e^y\\\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=e^y+(x+y)e^y=(x+y+1)e^y\end{cases}$$

Then when you simplify everything to find $\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt}$, remember to replace every instance of $x$ and $y$ with their corresponding expressions in terms of $t$.